# How to set the text of a TextView from Java

Tags: java, android

I need to randomize the text of a `TextView`.

I know how to randomize the stuff with the following example:

```
String[] epicstring={"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
Random r=new Random();
int randomnumber= r.nextInt(epicstring.length);
System.out.println(epicstring[randomnumber]);
```

I want to output the text into a `TextView`, but how can I do that?

Comment: _"output the text into a TextView, how can I do that though?"_ By reading [the TextView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView). It has a [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyTextView); // use with ID of your TextView
textView.setText(epicstring[randomnumber]);
```